# Can "compounded" be used as an adjective? For example "this is a compounded issue"?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, spoken-english

Today I found this sentence [on the CBC news site](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/british-columbia/after-hours-partying-garbage-in-vancouver-s-stanley-park-contributing-to-coyote-attacks-researcher-1.6125863):

> "We know that people have been feeding animals in the park. So that is contributing," she said. "I think this is **a compounded issue**."

For me it looks like "compounded" there was used as an adjective, but according to multiple dictionaries there is no such an adjective as "compounded". Google Ngram finds nothing too.

Could you help me with this, please?

Comment: The person probably means: an issue that is compounded by a, b or c. So, it's not explained but it's okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most verbs that can be used transitively (i.e., followed by an object) can be used passively.

> I cooked the food [active]
> *becomes*
> The food was cooked [passive]

Because English forms many adjectives out of the past participles of verbs, the adjective form of a verb is identical to the passive form.

> The raw fish is no good today. Please try some of the cooked fish.

Because this is true of almost every transitive verb, dictionary publishers do not create a separate entry for every past participle that can be used as an adjective.

**Compounded** is correctly formed according to the usual rules. I am familiar with its use largely in the context of medicine.

Answer (score 1):

Compounded is the past simple and past participle of the verb 'compound'. In English, many past and present participles of verbs can be used as adjectives.

[Compounded (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/compounded)